# Multiple Approval Processes only first process order Action gets created

Tags: workflow

I have two Approval Processes with different criteria on Account. When i submit the Account Object for Approval only the first process orders action is created and then after approval/reject second approval's action does not created.

To clarify I made both Approval Processes as same criteria and the result was same. How to get both Approvals Processes enter on request for approval.

To get clarified more, i tried to submit for approval through API.
https://na31.salesforce.com/services/data/v36.0/process/approvals/
and in the payload i used "processDefinitionNameOrId": "AccountApprovalOrder2".
In this case it actually created Action for Second Process Order.

Regards,

Harsha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have multiple approval processes execute where a single submitted record qualifies. [See SFSE answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/113771/multiple-approval-processes-only-first-process-order-action-gets-created/113772#)

Only the first one in the Process Order (as defined on the Approval Process page for the Object) will be chosen.

**Why would this be?**  Thought exercise:

If multiple approval processes could 'run' simultaneously, the record could be both locked (by process 1)  and unlocked (by process 2) at the same observation point in time (loosely akin to Heisenberg uncertainty principle).

To get the record to flow through the second approval process, you need to have different criteria and the user has to submit for approval a second time after the first approval process has completed.

I think SFDC designed this so you couldn't do simultaneously:

"Mom, can I have the car?" and 
"Dad, can I stay out all night?"

Dad wants to be asked after Mom has answered the question.

Comment: I understand Heisenberg uncertainty principle, however since it says "Process Order" I was expecting that sequential execution of Approvals.

Comment: So you mean, the Process Order is for order in which criteria matching is to be done? not for execution!!

Comment: crop1645: On this "To get the record to flow through the second approval process, you need to have different criteria and the user has to submit for approval a second time after the first approval process has completed." i tried by submitting for approval multiple times every time only the first process order action was getting created. Is this the behavior or anything wrong from my side?

Comment: the criteria for process 1 should exclude any object that has been approved by process 1; you'll need a field update in process 1 to set this on the object